# How to add a node at the end of a linked list?

Tags: c, list, struct, nodes

First of all before y'all tell me I checked the other questions on this site and I followed the instructions. Still my program has bugs .

here's the code i've made but it doesn't start at all

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}Tnode;

Tnode *head;

typedef Tnode *Tlist;

void insert(int);

void printlist();

Tnode *makenode(int x);

Tlist MakeList ();

void InsertAtEnd (Tlist list,int x);

void infoPrint (int info);

void PrintList(Tlist list);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n,i,x;
    Tlist list=MakeList();
    printf("Creiamo una lista; quanti elementi vuoi inserire ? ");//translation "how many elements in the list ?"

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n Inserisci valore da inserire ");//translation "insert the element" 
        scanf("%d",&x);
        InsertAtEnd(list,x);
        PrintList(list);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Tlist MakeList (){
return NULL;
}

void insert(int x){
    Tnode *temp= makenode(x);
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    }

Tnode *makenode(int x){
    Tnode *new=malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    if (new==NULL)
        return NULL;
    new->num=x;
    new->next=NULL;
    printf(".");
    return new;
}

void infoPrint (int info) {
    printf (" %d ", info);
}

void PrintList(Tlist list){
    Tnode *node=list;
    while(node!=NULL){
        infoPrint(node->num);
        node=node->next;
    }
}

void InsertAtEnd (Tlist head,int x){
    Tnode *newNode,*tmp;
    newNode=makenode(x);
    tmp=head;

    while(tmp->next!=NULL){
        tmp=tmp->next;
        tmp->next=newNode;

    }
}
```

When i build it there's 0 problems. When I run it it stops as soon as i insert the fisrt value of the list. 
How do i make it work?

Comment: changes made to `head` will not be persistent across function calls. You need to defined `head` as a double pointer if you intend to pass its value across

Comment: i tried with Tlist *head it gives me 1000 errors. it says `expected 'Tnode ** {aka struct node **}' but argument is of type 'Tlist {aka struct node *}' `

Comment: also `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]  tmp=head `

Comment: your MakeList is returning NULL directly. So ```list``` is NULL. You are further, sending that to ```insertAtEnd()```. And there tmp will be NULL as it is initialized to head - causing it to NOT enter the while loop and exit. In fact, it should dump core at the while statement. Do ```ulimit -c unlimited``` and run again to see if there's a core dump.

Comment: @Siddharth you were right how do i fix it tho ? :(

Comment: Check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You program has MakeList function which is returning NULL.

This NULL is being assigned to list.

You are then sending the list to insertAtEnd function.

While evaluating the `while statement`, it dumps core (segmentation fault) and the program exits.

That's the reason your program is abruptly exiting.

Make the below mods --

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *next;
}Tnode;

Tnode *head;

typedef Tnode *Tlist;

void insert(int);

void printlist();

Tnode *makenode(int x);

Tlist MakeList ();

Tlist InsertAtEnd (Tlist list,int x); // changed prototype

void infoPrint (int info);

void PrintList(Tlist list);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n,i,x;
    Tlist list=MakeList();
    printf("Creiamo una lista; quanti elementi vuoi inserire ? ");//translation "how many elements in the list ?"

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n Inserisci valore da inserire ");//translation "insert the element"
        scanf("%d",&x);
        list = InsertAtEnd(list,x); // changed call to function...
        PrintList(list);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Tlist MakeList (){
return NULL;
}

void insert(int x){
    Tnode *temp= makenode(x);
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    }

Tnode *makenode(int x){
    Tnode *new=malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    if (new==NULL)
        return NULL;
    new->num=x;
    new->next=NULL;
    printf(".");
    return new;
}

void infoPrint (int info) {
    printf (" %d ", info);
}

void PrintList(Tlist list){
    Tnode *node=list;
    while(node!=NULL){
        infoPrint(node->num);
        node=node->next;
    }
}

Tlist InsertAtEnd (Tlist head,int x){
    Tnode *newNode,*tmp;
    newNode=makenode(x);
    tmp=head;

    if (tmp == NULL)
        head = newNode;
    else
    {
            while(tmp->next!=NULL){
                    tmp=tmp->next;
            }
            tmp->next = newNode;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: It works fine now . Thanks for the help i still got the same problem with the function printlist i guess it's the same problem infact it doesn't get into the while i fix it the same way probably

Comment: Yes, the snippet I shared takes care of that and I got the output printing the list.

Comment: The other guys said a double pointer is needed or the changes on head are not effective. This code still works tho. How's that possible.

Comment: Because you are returning the pointer from the insert function...

Answer (score 0):

The function `InsertAtEnd` is the problem.

You are not taking care of the case of the first element. For this the function definition needs to be modified. You can pass a double pointer to the `head` to this function.

Also, the assignment of `tmp->next=newNode;` should be after the for loop.

You should avoid creating a pointer type `TList` It is much cleaner and easier to just pass a pointer to the `Tnode`

```
void InsertAtEnd (Tnode ** head,int x){
    Tnode *newNode,*tmp;
    newNode=makenode(x);
    tmp=*head;

    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(tmp->next!=NULL){
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next=newNode;

    }
}

// in main call it with
InsertAtEnd(&list,x);
```

Comment: The siddarth's modified code works fine . Even without the double pointer .

Comment: Both options will work. You can select any one that you want.